# ACF Repeater not displaying first in the list

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

When displaying my repeater field onto the front-end it will display everything in that list apart from the very first item. I would like it to display everything in the repeater.

```
<?php if( have_rows('the_list') ): the_row(); ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php while( have_rows('the_list') ): the_row(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h6><?php the_sub_field('name') ?></h6>
            <p><?php the_sub_field('number') ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help.

Comment: @mbacon40 I've added the code snippet i'm using to pull this

Comment: can you check your first row in backend is empty of not?

Answer (score 1):

You are running `the_row();` twice. Removing this from after your if statement should fix your issue.

Here is an updated snippet:

```
<?php if( have_rows('the_list') ): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php while( have_rows('the_list') ): the_row(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h6><?php the_sub_field('name') ?></h6>
                <p><?php the_sub_field('number') ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php global $post; ?>
<?php if( have_rows('the_list'), $post->ID ): ?>
 <div class="row">
  <?php while( have_rows('the_list'), $post->ID ): the_row(); ?>
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <h6><?php the_sub_field('name') ?></h6>
    <p><?php the_sub_field('number') ?></p>
   </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
 </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```